# iOS: Read data from .plist in dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I would like to retrieve data from a plist in my .app directory.
I can not figure out how to get sub-dictionary data. For instance, I would like to get the `MemoriesDictionary/Memory1/Event1/EventName` value.

[image: Dictionaries]

I am able to get the `MemoryCount` value into `iMemCount` just fine with:

```
int iMemCount;

//Do file searching/getting for plist

NSString *plistDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"memoryDetails" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"array: %@",plistDirectory);

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: plistDirectory]) //4
{
    NSLog(@"exists");
    NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistDirectory];

    iMemCount = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"MemoryCount"] intValue];


} else {
    NSLog(@"Does Not Exist");
    iMemCount = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *string = savedStock[@"MemoriesDictionary"][@"Memory1"][@"Event1"][@"EventName"];
```

**Edit**

You could also rewrite:

```
int iMemCount;
iMemCount = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"MemoryCount"] intValue];
```

as

```
NSInteger iMemCount;
iMemCount = [savedStock[@"MemoryCount"] integerValue];
```

You really should be taking into account the possibility of your iOS code running on a 64-bit processor and use the appropriate platform safe types (`NSInteger`, `CGFloat`, `CFIndex`, etc)

Comment: Works great but when I try and access int n = (NSUInteger) savedStock[@"MemoriesDictionary"][@"Memory1"][@"EventCount"];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n]); I recieve a very large, incorrect number

Comment: You aren't using the method i wrote. Look at your plist specification; there is no key for EventCount under Memory1

Answer (score 1):

Note also that using an NSMutableDictionary here may not do what you expect: the top-level dictionary will be mutable but all the sub-objects (arrays, dictionaries) will be immutable and throw an exception if you try to access them.

In general I’d caution against doing lookups several levels deep in dictionaries, because it’s usually a sign that you’re doing something the hard way. The pattern I like to follow is create classes that can read and write themselves to dictionaries, and then when I read in a file create instances that can be queried directly.

Dealing with a bunch of mutable dictionaries with a bunch of string keys is a recipe for heartache and disaster. You lose compile-time type checking and compile-time variable name checking and readability.

Also, I don’t know if this is a contrived example file, but I wouldn’t write the count to the file explicitly—just calculate it as needed. Duplicating data leads to data being out of sync. And it seems like MemoriesDictionary really wants to be an array, if the names of the memories are inside the sub-dictionaries, and the keys are used to keep the memories in order.

Comment: So what would the ideal method be of storing data which is dynamically creating in level grouping?

Comment: @Wil; Well thought out answers like this give us "fastest guns in the West" answerers a bad name. Please stop. Thanks.